# How do I know NFC Passport Chips read which DataGroup?

Tags: ios, iphone, nfc, core-nfc

I am reading the German e-Passport and it's reading the Datagroups 1,2,3 & 14 and SOD, COM also. Now, I want to read the Datagroup 11 which hold the additional details. But the German Passport doesn't read the optional data. So, how do I know Which passports read which Groups?
I have gone through the [ICAO 9303](https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p11_cons_en.pdf) but didn't get any chance to get this information.

Comment: try to look through the https://github.com/AndyQ/NFCPassportReader, hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I am using this library but my question is more about: Is it possible to read other DataGroups or not? If yes then how, If no then why?
As I said in German Passport I can read only DG1, DG2, DG3, DG14 and SOD hash keys. So why I am unable to read the other groups.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I read DG32, DG33, DG34, but flow is the same, here is some example of how to implement DG11 file reading using `NFCPassportReader`

```
public class DataGroup {

    public var elements: [String: String] = [:]
```

// I added this dictionary to get value by key from documentation

```
class DG11: DataGroup {

        private let tags = [0x5F0E, 0x5F0F, 0x5F10, 0x5F11, 0x5F2B]

        required init(_ data: [UInt8]) throws {
            try super.init(data)
            datagroupType = .DG11
        }

        override func parse(_ data: [UInt8]) throws {
            var tag = try getNextTag()
            if tag != 0x5C { throw TagError.InvalidResponse }
            _ = try getNextValue()
            try tags.forEach { _ in
                tag = try getNextTag()
                parseBody(try getNextValue(), key: String(tag, radix: 16, uppercase: true))
            }
            print(elements)
        }

        private func parseBody(_ data: [UInt8], key: String) {
            elements[key] = String(bytes: data[0...], encoding: .utf8)
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Do you really read DG32, DG33 and 34 because ICAO says passport have only 16 DataGroups. So, I am stuck now. Thanks for the above code I will check it.

Comment: Ukrainain passport has above mentioned groups, I read all of them. You should read official documents of e-passports content, it is in open source

Comment: But I didn't read anywhere about DG32,33,34....? Do you have some documentation of the same? Can you please let me know which DG's read from the Ukrainian Passport?